# SQl query to Break up rows to batches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
    OrderID Product Quantity
    1       A            800
    2       B            700
    3       C            300
```

I need a select query in order to split the total quantity of 1800 to a number of batches (eg 3) like this

```
   BatchNo Product Quantity
   1       A       600
   2       A       200
   2       B       400
   3       B       300
   3       C       300
```

Is there any way to do this as a select query ?

I use SQL 2016

Comment: Honestly, SQL Server is not your friends for tasks such as this. You would be better doing to programmatically.

Comment: what are the rules ? Why is 800 = 600 and 200 and why is 700 = 400 and 300 ?

Comment: And why is a product suddenly being converted to random batches? This makes no sense at all.

Comment: I need 3 batched, so every batch has to be 600

Comment: Give us an example of code please. If you do not try, you won't find out what is wrong.

Comment: What do you need 3 batched supposed to mean? This sounds a lot like a watered down version of the classic bin packing issue. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: Let me explain the real problem 
Our ERP  system has a table with product LOTs. 
Each LOT has a quantity and an expiration date. 
The problem is that our production system has a specific capacity, so in order to produce a number of final products we need to split our process into several batches
In the example, the capacity is 600 and in order to produce 1800 products we need 3 batches. 
First batch will use Lot A , second batch will use Lots A and B and finally 3rd batch will use lot B and lot C 
Our system has to produce 5 production orders

Comment: @Harris I would try SSIS to create an Agent to do your work. Here is a link on how to batch process with SSIS -
 https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1504/how-to-implement-batch-processing-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/  HTH!

Answer (score 1):

```
ceiling(cast(row_number()(order by (select 1)) as decimal (10, 2)) / 3) as BatchNo
```

This should do what you require. Just add it to your `select` statement. You can change the number you are dividing by splitting it up into more batches.

Answer (score 0):

Imho the fastest way to do this is write for example CLR SqlProcedure that would read data row by row and produce output record every time "batch" has 300 or more using  `SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart()` / `SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd()` / `SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow()` . It is easy to produce output data in single pass with c#, not so much in tsql

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void MakeBatches()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT [...]"), connection);
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            using (reader)
            {
                var outputRecord = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData[]
                    {
                        new SqlMetaData("BatchNo", SqlDbType.Int),
                        new SqlMetaData("Product", SqlDbType.Char),
                        new SqlMetaData("Quantity", SqlDbType.Int)
                    }
                );

                SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(outputRecord);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var orderId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    var product = (char)reader.GetValue(1);
                    var quantity = reader.GetInt32(2);

                    if ([...]) //put some logic here 
                    {
                        outputRecord.SetInt32(0, batchNo_value_here);
                        [...] //insert record here
                        SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(outputRecord);
                    }
                }
                SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();

            }
        }
    }
}
```